# php foreach loop only returns values for first iteration in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, inner-join

I seem to be unable to identify why my foreach loop is able to loop for all 5 of the ProductionOrderID's created but only returns the data for the first ID.

It is my understanding that the array is looping correctly as you can see the **current result** here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhzIC.png but what's weird is ID:2 has no table being generated and ID 5 has 2 tables created, all blank as per the imgur screenshot just linked.

I've doubled checked my sample data, there are 5 unique records for each table with no duplications or issues that I could find.

**EDIT: 1**
I forgot to mention the desired result to clarify how I wish the looping to work. Please see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOLIv.png (Cheers Sand).

**EDIT: 2**
Here is an Export of the SQL: https://pastebin.com/MG2gtASu
And here is my **ERD** should it help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nlJu.png

**EDIT: 3**
New, updated code (Thanks Sand):

```
<?php
include('OrderCore/connect-db.php');
$POIds = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProductionOrderID FROM ProductionOrder" ) ) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $POIds[] = $row->ProductionOrderID;
    }
}
foreach ( $POIds as $index => $OrderId ) {
    if ( $result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM ProductionOrder AS p
    LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderStatus AS s ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = s.ProductionOrderStatusID ) 
    LEFT JOIN NotGood AS n ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = n.NGID ) 
    LEFT JOIN BatchOrder AS b ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = b.BatchID ) 
    LEFT JOIN Brand AS bd ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = bd.BrandID ) 
    LEFT JOIN CustomerOrder AS co ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = co.COID ) 
    LEFT JOIN Customer AS c ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = c.CustomerID ) 
    LEFT JOIN CustomerOrderStatus AS cos ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = cos.COStatusID ) 
    WHERE p.ProductionOrderID='$OrderId'") ) {
        while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
            print "<h1>Order: $OrderId</h1>";
            print "<table class='table table-striped'>";
            print "<tr> <th>PO ID</th> <th>PO #</th> <th>Order Quantity</th> <th>Balance Left</th> <th>Production Date</th> <th>Production Order Status</th> <th>Not Good ID</th> </tr>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionOrderID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->PONum . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->OrderQTY . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BalLeftNum . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionDate . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionOrderStatusID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->NGID . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</table>";
            //BatchOrder
            print "<table class='table table-striped'>";
            print "<tr> <th>Batch ID</th> <th>Brand Name</th> <th>Batch Quantity</th> <th>Availability Date</th> <th>Remaining Balance</th> <th>Production Order ID</th> </tr>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BatchID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BrandID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BatchQTY . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->AvailDate . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->RemainBal . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ProductionOrderID . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</table>";
            //CustomerOrder
            print "<table class='table table-striped'>";
            print "<tr> <th>Customer ID</th> <th>Customer Name</th> <th>Invoice Quantity</th> <th>Invoice #</th> <th>Shipping Date</th> <th>Batch ID</th> <th>CO Status</th> </tr>";
            print "<td>" . $row->COID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->CustomerID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->InvoiceQTY . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->InvoiceNum . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->ShipDate . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->BatchID . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $row->COStatusID . "</td>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</table>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "No results to display!";
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You want to loop 5 per page or 5 records each time the `SQL` runs ? or you just want display the record in your table?

Comment: I want to loop every record (ProductionOrder) there is; which is currently 5 but could be 5 or 500.

Comment: Ok can you tell me wht does `$POIds` do ?

Comment: That is my attempt to create an array which stores all of the `ProductionOrderID`'s in which gets called as `$OrderId` in the `foreach` loop. The result currently looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/MIhfB0s.png

Comment: Yes the thing I was trying to figure out is why you're using a `foreach` if you want display what's in your data table just use a `while` loop it will loop until there's no more data to display.

Comment: The reason I started using a `foreach` is because I was trying to figure out a way to generate a new set of HTML tables for each new ID. 'ProductionOrderID' as the main table which has a child table 'BatchOrder' which has a child table of its own 'CustomerOrder'. 

Without the `foreach`, it was generating all of the records for all tables as new rows in only 3 html tables. Here is an attempt to demonstrate the final, desired result: https://i.imgur.com/4h7l49p.png

Comment: Have been reading you question over and over so this is what I understand you want display each and every record you have in your table with there own `HTML` table in the out put am I right ?

Comment: Yeah you should have mention that in your question it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have added that to the original question.

Comment: You should put this under while loop when you need to print the first table 5 time  print "<table class='table table-striped'>";
    print "<tr> <th>PO ID</th> <th>PO #</th> <th>Order Quantity</th> <th>Balance Left</th> <th>Production Date</th> <th>Production Order Status</th> <th>Not Good ID</th> </tr>";

Comment: @SaadSuri When I do that, it only displays once as you can see here: https://i.imgur.com/9SK8s5h.png

Comment: I think the problem is with the `SQL` it seems like it's only picking up the first data row and the `JOIN` the others after that it stops. It's not the `foreach` or the `while`.

Comment: @Sand I'm going to start combing over my SQL but I've included a copy of the code + ERD in my original post if that provides clarity for anyone else.

Comment: I think I found your problem, I used your `SQL` export to create the database structure and executed your `SQL` (I removed the `WEHER` clues) and it only gave me the 1st data row from all the tables. The problem is in your _notgood_ table. When the `SQL` executes it tries to match the data when one table has lesser number of data `SQL` is going display what it can match skips the other in other table even they get joined. As I said problem is with the `SQL` your PHP is fine.

Comment: I updated my answer have a look.

Comment: Thanks Sand, your logic makes complete sense and I've changed my BatchOrder JOIN to reference the POId not the BOId.

And having the batches appear in their own table is the desired result so I don't need to add another loop but I'm still only seeing 1 batch per PO after the fix. Did you see the correct behaviour after changing the JOIN ON in your version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out why it's happening it's due to the join type `INNER` [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) will help you to understand.

Found the problem why it was just showing 1 batch of data. It's because you were equaling the `p.ProductionOrderID = b.BatchID` so what happens is query looks to match your production ID to batch ID and your batch ID is unique so there's no duplicates which leads to showing a single data record from that matching line. What you really want to do is to match the production ID in your batch table because that is the relationship between your production table and the batch table. Now when you run this it will draw tables till the end of batch's.

If you want to show all the batch details in one column in your HTML then suggest `while` or `foreach` and you don't need another `SQL` you already have the rows selected. EX:`$row["BatchQTY"]`

And here's my solution.

```
if ( $result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT * 
FROM ProductionOrder AS p
LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderStatus AS s ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = s.ProductionOrderStatusID ) 
LEFT JOIN NotGood AS n ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = n.NGID ) 
LEFT JOIN BatchOrder AS b ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = b.ProductionOrderID)//Changed this equation 
LEFT JOIN Brand AS bd ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = bd.BrandID ) 
LEFT JOIN CustomerOrder AS co ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = co.COID ) 
LEFT JOIN Customer AS c ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = c.CustomerID ) 
LEFT JOIN CustomerOrderStatus AS cos ON ( p.ProductionOrderID = cos.COStatusID )
    WHERE p.ProductionOrderID='$OrderId'")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! And for the visual examples, that definitely helps to clarify the different types. Thanks again for taking the time to understand and help.

Comment: I did notice that it's not displaying more than 1 Batch or Customer Order per Production Order. Do you have any advice on how to loop through each of them>

Comment: Sorry I was offline when you commented. No problem your problem also gave me a chance to brush up on my `SQL`.  And about your 2nd comment is this after correcting the `SQL` ? and what you mean is your system only shows 1 set of data when there more under the same _Customer Order_ ? Also are your using the same `SQL` or this is different one ?

Comment: Hi Sand, no worries. So I've updated my original question again with the updated code and that's what I'm using right now. Here you can see it's working fantastically for each new `ProductionOrder`: 

https://i.imgur.com/JXNzEfS.png The only issue is it's only showing me 1 `BatchOrder` and 1 customer order per `ProductionOrder`. 

There can be more than 1 `BatchOrder` attached to a `ProductionOrder` and there can be more than 1 `CustomerOrder` attached to a `BatchOrder`.

I've spent a while trying to create a loop within a loop but not had much success so far!

Comment: Ah ok think this can be done by using `SQL` it self can you do me a favor and give me a `SQL` paste bin with some data which I can recreate your said scenario so I can test it out on my own.

Comment: Yeah thx but I used your old details and populated the DB and I think I see why it's only showing 1 data row just give me some time to confirm and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Type inside the while loop

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

So you can see the behavior of your data. I think the main problem raise from your ***select query***.